# Great source to learn Logo and Web Design software skills

Tags: adobe-photoshop, education

What is a good (preferably free) source(s) for learning photoshop? I would prefer a source you actually used to learn Photoshop basics from ground zero.

I want to use Photoshop mainly for web design, logo design, and other software design purposes.

Comment: Hi there! I migrated your question to the main site because you posted it on Meta. However, I think your question has been asked here before. Take a look at [this one](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4792/resources-for-learning-photoshop-cs5).

Comment: This is a bit broad question, it really depends on WHAT you want to do with Photoshop. So if you could elaborate then your more likely to get meaningful answers. I mean digitally coloring and inking comics is different from denoising, sharpening and color correcting photography, which again is different from designing flyers for print.

Comment: @joojaa Sorry about the lack of details. I want to use Photoshop mainly for web design and other software and logo design purposes.

Comment: For logos and logo like entities like icons and symbols you should probably learn illustrator then. (NOTE: its easier to learn Illustrator first and then Photoshop)

Comment: @joojaa Oh I didn't know what Illustrator was. Thank you! It's perfect for what I need! Add that as an answer so I can close my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As mentioned by @joojaa*

For logos or logo like entities (ie. icons, symbols) and Web Design, it is better to just learn Adobe Illustrator.

*It is also easier to learn Illustrator first and then Photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

Very, very ancient (CS2), but very, very good are the basic tutorials from the School of Photoshop by David Leggett's [Tutorial9](http://www.tutorial9.net/). Begin at the beginning, the king said:

- http://www.tutorial9.net/tutorials/photoshop-tutorials/getting-started-in-photoshop/
- http://www.tutorial9.net/tutorials/photoshop-tutorials/using-palettes-in-photoshop/
- http://www.tutorial9.net/uncategorized/photoshops-basic-tools/
- http://www.tutorial9.net/uncategorized/working-with-layers-in-photoshop/
- http://www.tutorial9.net/uncategorized/the-selection-tools/
- http://www.tutorial9.net/uncategorized/retouch-and-healing-tools/
- http://www.tutorial9.net/uncategorized/painting-tools/
- http://www.tutorial9.net/uncategorized/drawing-and-type-tools/
- http://www.tutorial9.net/uncategorized/using-transform-in-photoshop/
- http://www.tutorial9.net/uncategorized/create-a-simple-flyer/
- http://www.tutorial9.net/uncategorized/saving-images-for-the-web/
- http://www.tutorial9.net/uncategorized/photoshops-filters/
- http://www.tutorial9.net/uncategorized/layer-styles-in-photoshop/

Then stop.

Comment: @vincent I think you dont like tutorial9, lol

Comment: @Matt I only dislike them for taking down the overview page of this top-notch beginner's guide. If they hadn't, I wouldn't have to give the entire list of links :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several sources for Photoshop-beginners to start learning, but most of the ones i know are not free (at least the good ones).

I would recommend to find a tutorial (just google) for anything you wanna do. Following the steps of a tutorial will make you understand how photoshop works. Basics as well as more difficult stuff. Imho Photoshop defenitely is a learning by doing thing. At least that's what worked very well for me, starting off with photoshop.

Hope this helps. Sry for bad english.